# Is there a way to play a live audio stream through Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I am trying to create an app where you can listen to radio streams from your phone.  Is this possible with Kivy?

I am building this app for my high school radio station.  I've tried the SoundLoader but that didn't seem to work.

Here is the code I have for playing the live-stream.

```py
class ListenWindow(Screen):
    sound = SoundLoader.load('stream.mp3')
    sound.play()
```

Here is the output I receive.

```
[WARNING] Deprecated property "<AliasProperty name=filename>" of object "<kivy.core.audio.audio_gstplayer.SoundGstplayer object at 0x03DFE378>" was accessed, it will be removed in a future version
[WARNING] [AudioGstplayer] b"No decoder available for type 'text/uri-list'."
[ERROR  ] [AudioGstplayer] b'Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.'
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[ERROR  ] [AudioGstplayer] b'Internal data stream error.'
```

I tried to update GStreamer through pip but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: I've never used Kivy, but what's the stream format you're trying to play?  The error message implies that you're not using the right URL.  Is this a SHOUTcast server, by chance?

Comment: I’m using the mp3 file I downloaded.  So I’m trying to play the file.  It’s an icecast server.

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded an MP3 and not an M3U?

Comment: It was originally an m3u file but I changed it to an mp3.  After I did this, it still played in VLC.  So I figured it was okay.  It still doesn't work but gives a different error.

Comment: Too long for one comment
`[INFO   ] [AudioGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.16.0.0
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_gstplayer, audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for <D:\fredi\Python Projects\wahsapp\stream.m3u>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\fredi\Python Projects\wahsapp\WAHS.py", line 17, in <module>
     class ListenWindow(Screen):
   File "D:\fredi\Python Projects\wahsapp\WAHS.py", line 19, in ListenWindow
     sound.play()
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'`

Comment: When you say you "changed it to an MP3", I assume you mean you just renamed it?  VLC supports M3Us and would have done some automatic detection, which is why it would have been able to play it.  If you open up that M3U in any text editor, you'll see the URLs to the actual streams.  Use those stream URLs witn your Python script/Gstreamer.

Comment: Okay.  I replaced the 'stream.mp3' with the link to the live stream and it worked.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cool, glad that worked!  I wrote up the details in an answer below, for others to find later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icecast/SHOUTcast streams are essentially HTTP Progressive streams, where the media data is continually encoded, streamed to clients, and played back.  When this type of streaming started, web browsers weren't able to play back the stream.  Therefore, if you linked directly to the stream, the browser would continuously download a never-ending "file".

To get around this, M3U and PLS playlists were used.  The idea being that in-browser, you can link to a playlist which was downloaded and subsequently opened in the user's media player.  The media player reads the playlist, finds the actual URL to the stream, and then makes its own HTTP request to the stream and plays it.

When you're using something like Gstreamer, to play the stream you need to use the actual stream URL.  That is, you need to parse the M3U or PLS playlist file yourself, find the stream URL, and then open it.  In your case, since you know that you're only working with one station, you can just open that playlist in a text editor to find the stream URL.